# Curve fitting data I imported from excel

Tags: fitting, excel

This is my first time posting here, so sorry if I break any rules.

There is this excel document from which I imported  two columns of data to mathematica. I need to fit the data into a curve so that I can get the equation which relates the two columns of data. I imported it to mathematica by using

```
t = Import["For Studies/Temperature.xlsx"];
```

It seemed to work and I was able to make a plot using `ListPlot`. However when I try to make the fit using `Fit`, it throws up the error

> "First argument 
>   {....}
>    in Fit is not a list or a rectangular array."

I used the Fit command as

```
Fit[t, {1, x, x^2, x^3 }, x];
```

The documentation about this is rather confusing and I'm kind of new to Mathematica, so any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Check that `t[[1]]` is the first data row ...

Comment: Without your xls file or data, it is difficult to find the problem. How about pasting a part of the imported data here that allows reproduction of the problem?

Comment: The problem may be the fact that importing an excel file results in a list of lists, one for each sheet in the excel file, even in the case that there is only one sheet. Try checking the structure of the results of import. If that is the case, you could try to use `t[[1]]` instead of `t` in your `Fit` expression. `ListPlot` handles lists of datasets just fine, so you wouldn't have noticed there.

Comment: @belisarius No, that might be the problem. When I try that I get the all the data back. Is there anyway to correct that?

Comment: @SharanBanagiri And what is `t[[1,1]]`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
t=Import["For Studies/Temperature.xlsx","Data"]
```

And if your data has headers in the first row use this:

```
t=Import["For Studies/Temperature.xlsx","Data"][[1]][[2;;]]
```

and this will select only the first two columns:

```
t=Import["For Studies/Temperature.xlsx","Data"][[1]][[2;;,{1,2}]]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yay, explicitly making it choose the first two columns worked. Thanks a lot.